# Spring Rest API, receiving one or list of object using same URL

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I want to insert one or list of object using same URL :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/subject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void addSubject(@ModelAttricbute Subject subject){
         ... // Inserting a subject
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/subject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void addSubject(@RequestBody Subject[] subject){
         ... // Inserting all the subject in the array
}
```

I want to be able to do those 2 things without changing the URL of Request.

Thanks in advance